# How should I email professors regarding online research during covid-19?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, internship, research-assistantship, covid-19

So I've been accepted into a masters program and there is this professor that I really want to get involved with hopefully as a research assistant. And since many if not most researches are being conducted online, I was wondering if its a good idea to email the professor to see if there is any way I can get exposure to his research by either working as his assistant or intern. I'd appreciate any comments!!

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.

Sending an email is the best way to find out if a particular professor/researcher is available. You can reach out to them via Email introducing yourself and your research area and what you intend to look into/research keeping in view the professor's research output.

If they dont reply then you can send a follow-up email after a week or so.

Hope this helps.